# What does for (; uint64_count && !*value; uint64_count--) mean

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand what this function does in pratice:

```
    inline std::size_t get_significant_uint64_count_uint(
        const std::uint64_t *value, std::size_t uint64_count)
    {
        value += uint64_count - 1;
        for (; uint64_count && !*value; uint64_count--)
        {
            value--;
        }

        return uint64_count;
    }
```

It looks like it modifies `value` but also `uint64_count`. I couldn't find what `&&` does but I guess here it's for "AND". Anyways, it looks like the for loop runs until `uint64_count>0` and `*value!=0`. But I don't get the logic.

Function is from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/SEAL/blob/5c586e2480dc0a43fb76a23a3dcc3daecb3764e8/native/src/seal/util/uintcore.h#L255)

Comment: && is logical AND.

Comment: looks like a while loop would be much clearer

Answer (score 2):

> It looks like it modifies `value` but also `uint64_count`

Yes.

> I couldn't find what `&&` does

Really? Any [decent C++ reference/book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/) should cover logical operators, in this case [logical AND](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical).

> I guess here it's for "AND"

Yes.

> it looks like the for loop runs until `uint64_count>0` and `*value!=0`.

No.  It runs until either `uint64_count` is 0, or `*value` is not 0.

Answer (score 1):

Ugly code.

```
inline std::size_t get_significant_uint64_count_uint(
    const std::uint64_t *value, std::size_t uint64_count)
{
    value += uint64_count - 1;
    for (; uint64_count && !*value; uint64_count--)
    {
        value--;
    }

    return uint64_count;
}
```

Okay, remember that you're passing both arguments by value. So modifying value or count doesn't do anything outside this method. They're copies of the originals.

So, value is a pointer into memory. The code increments it by the count, then the code starts looking from that location back towards the beginning for a null byte.

So I guess it's trying to find the count of bytes to the final null in the data.

Why? No clue.

Comment: "*looking ... for a null byte*" -> "*looking ... for a **non-null** byte*", actually. "*it's trying to find the count of bytes to the final null*" -> "*it's trying to find the count of bytes to the final **non-null***", since it loops while `*value` is 0, so it breaks when `*value` is not 0.

Answer (score 0):

The function runs from the end of an array pointed by `value` until finds a value of 0 in the array or reached the end of the array, and returns the index in the array of the value equals to 0.

Comment: "*until finds a value of 0*" -> "*until it finds a **non-zero value***", actually. It loops while `*value` is 0, so it breaks when `*value` is not 0.